# A practical way to color pairs of brackets

Tags: align, amsmath, tcolorbox, amsfonts

I would like to find an option in order to color automatically pairs of brackets because I am starting to have a very long equation (that is splitted in two lines) and I was wondering if it was possible to distinguish pairs of `\Biggl` and `\Biggr`

I know that there are some alternatives like :

```
$\textcolor{red}{\big(} a\big)$
```

But as I said : it would only make my coding more and more complicated so I am looking for a simpler way to do so.

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%%MATHS%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
h_{i}^{n+1} &= h_{i}^{n} + \frac{4 \Delta t}{\Delta R} \Biggl[ \Biggl(\frac{h_{i+1}^n + h_{i}^n}{2} \Biggr)^3  \Biggl(R_{i+1/2} \Biggl(\frac{h_{i+1}^{n+1} - h_{i}^{n+1}}{\Delta R} \Biggr)  + 8B\sqrt{R_{i+1/2}} \Biggl[4 R_{i+1/2} \Biggl (\frac{-h_{i-1}^{n+1} + 3h_{i}^{n+1} - 3h_{i+1}^{n+1} + h_{i+2}^{n+1} }{(\Delta R)^3} \Biggr)
\\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}
+\Biggl(\frac{h_{i-1}^{n+1} - h_{i}^{n+1} - h_{i+1}^{n+1}+h_{i+2}^{n+1} }{(\Delta R)^2}\Biggr)\Biggr) + (R_{i+1/2})^2 \Biggl(  \frac{h_{i-2}^{n+1} - 3h_{i-1}^{n+1} + 2h_{i}^{n+1} + 2h_{i+1}^{n+1}-3h_{i+2}^{n+1} + h_{i+3}^{n+1}}{2(\Delta R)^4} \Biggr) \Biggr]\Biggr]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you very much for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an ugly method, but it will works:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%%MATHS%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\splBiggl[1]{\color{blue}\Bigg#1\color{black}}%
\newcommand\splBiggr[1]{\color{blue}\Bigg#1\color{black}}%



\begin{align*}
h_{i}^{n+1} &= h_{i}^{n} + \frac{4 \Delta t}{\Delta R} \splBiggl[
\splBiggl(\frac{h_{i+1}^n + h_{i}^n}{2} \splBiggr)^3
\splBiggl(R_{i+1/2} \splBiggl(\frac{h_{i+1}^{n+1} -
h_{i}^{n+1}}{\Delta R} \splBiggr)  + 8B\sqrt{R_{i+1/2}} \splBiggl[4
R_{i+1/2} \splBiggl (\frac{-h_{i-1}^{n+1} + 3h_{i}^{n+1} -
3h_{i+1}^{n+1} + h_{i+2}^{n+1} }{(\Delta R)^3} \splBiggr)
\\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}
+\splBiggl(\frac{h_{i-1}^{n+1} - h_{i}^{n+1} -
h_{i+1}^{n+1}+h_{i+2}^{n+1} }{(\Delta R)^2}\splBiggr)\splBiggr) +
(R_{i+1/2})^2 \splBiggl(  \frac{h_{i-2}^{n+1} - 3h_{i-1}^{n+1} +
2h_{i}^{n+1} + 2h_{i+1}^{n+1}-3h_{i+2}^{n+1} +
h_{i+3}^{n+1}}{2(\Delta R)^4} \splBiggr) \splBiggr]\splBiggr]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works as expected